# Possible bug in Java 8 Update 45 on Windows 8

Tags: java, image, rgb, race-condition, compiler-bug

This code takes an input image and produces an output image dimensioned twice as large. The first four lines in the inner loop write four identical-sized copies of the original, the last four lines should overwrite the small images with one copy of the input image twice as large as the original.

The code compiles and runs without error on Java 8 Update 45 on Windows 8. The resulting image is not, as expected, one large copy of the input. The lower half of the output is as expected, but the upper half consists of the two original-sized copies of the input written by the first two lines inside the loop. Commenting out these two lines leads to the initally expected result, so it seems that the first two lines get executed last, not first, despite appearing first in the source code.

**Is this a compiler bug, a race condition in the runtime, or a brain fart on my behalf?**

If requested, I'll put up examples somewhere.

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] orgs) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(new File("cat.jpg"));

        int w=pic.getWidth(),h=pic.getHeight();
        BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(w+w,h+h,pic.getType());
        for (int y=0;y<h;y++) {
            for (int x=0;x<w;x++) {
                int pixel = pic.getRGB(x,y);
                // write four small copies
                out.setRGB(x    ,y    ,pixel); // these two lines apparently are
                out.setRGB(x+w  ,y    ,pixel); // executed after the remaining six
                out.setRGB(x    ,y+h  ,pixel);
                out.setRGB(x+w  ,y+h  ,pixel);
                // overwrite with one large copy
                out.setRGB(x+x  ,y+y  ,pixel);
                out.setRGB(x+x+1,y+y  ,pixel);
                out.setRGB(x+x  ,y+y+1,pixel);
                out.setRGB(x+x+1,y+y+1,pixel);
            }
        }

        ImageIO.write(out, "bmp", new File("./cat.bmp"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `out.getGraphics().drawImage(pic, 0, 0, w * 2, h * 2, null)` instead of doing each pixel manually?

Comment: @BretC I encountered a reproducible problem which I didn't understand. Assuming my code was correct, that would have indicated a worrying problem with the compiler. Assuming my code was not correct, that indicated a worrying problem with my brain. Also, I plan to do some pretty low-level image processing. And I'm still learning, as one might deduce from the classname. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a brain fart I'm afraid. Becaue you're doing everything in the same loop, executing the initial four lines (small copies) in later iterations ends up overwriting the pixels that were written by the last four lines (large copy) in earlier iterations.

I'm not sure I worded that brilliantly but hopefully you'll see what I mean.

Comment: That's a succinct statement showing that my (implicit) assumption that the writes do not overlap is incorrect. It did not explain what exactly happened, though.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to demonstrate what's happening. Suppose your image is:

```
┌───╥───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │ B │
├───╫───┼───┤
│ 1 ║ C │ D │
└───╨───┴───┘
```

For x=0, y=0, after the first four lines:

```
┌───╥───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │   │ A │   │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1 ║   │   │   │   │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2 ║ A │   │ A │   │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3 ║   │   │   │   │
└───╨───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

After the last four lines:

```
┌───╥───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │ A │ A │   │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1 ║ A │ A │   │   │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2 ║ A │   │ A │   │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3 ║   │   │   │   │
└───╨───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

For x=1, y=0, after first four lines:

```
┌───╥───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │ B │ A │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1 ║ A │ A │   │   │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2 ║ A │ B │ A │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3 ║   │   │   │   │
└───╨───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

After the last four lines:

```
┌───╥───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │ B │ B │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1 ║ A │ A │ B │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2 ║ A │ B │ A │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3 ║   │   │   │   │
└───╨───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

For x = 0, y = 1, first four lines:

```
┌───╥───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │ B │ B │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1 ║ C │ A │ C │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2 ║ A │ B │ A │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3 ║ C │   │ C │   │
└───╨───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Last four lines:

```
┌───╥───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │ B │ B │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1 ║ C │ A │ C │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2 ║ C │ C │ A │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3 ║ C │ C │ C │   │
└───╨───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

For x=1, y=1, first four lines:

```
┌───╥───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │ B │ B │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1 ║ C │ D │ C │ D │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2 ║ C │ C │ A │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3 ║ C │ D │ C │ D │
└───╨───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

And with the final four lines:

```
┌───╥───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   ║ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
╞═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│ 0 ║ A │ B │ B │ B │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1 ║ C │ D │ C │ D │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2 ║ C │ C │ D │ D │
├───╫───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3 ║ C │ D │ D │ D │
└───╨───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

This is not the result that you expected, and it stems from the fact that in each iteration, you go back and overwrite four pixels. Some of these pixels belong to your double image.

Comment: I like that text-art table! =)

Comment: Me too. ;) It does not really explain things, though. But your answer was helpful in working out the exact mechanism. BTW, did notice the right half of the first line is not A B but B B? I didn't notice that with my test image until I saw it here.

Comment: Yeah, @WolframSchmied - and the bottom is `CD` rather than `CC`. Noticed that too in your image?

Comment: Yes. You can't see it in the video in my answer, but the right half of the topmost line are pixels from the big image, it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the small images are written line by line starting from the top and from the middle simultaneously. The large image also starts from the top, but "moves" twice as fast. So, the small "slow" images in the upper half overwrite the fast large pixels written earlier, while in the lower half the already written "small" pixels are overwritten by the fast front arriving later.

I've uploaded an [animation on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttKsVDUyQJ8) showing the process.

(Both Phil's and RealSkeptic's answers were helpful in finding the explanation. I chose Phil's answer because his answer was closer to explaining what exactly happend.)